# getting profilepath value in batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory

I need to write a batchfile to make some directory content moves.

How can I get into a batch variable the value of the profilepath returned by the command net user xxx /domain?

Comment: %userprofile% is what you're looking for. It's a standard variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop and put the `net user` command piped over to a [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command using `tokens` and `delims` accordingly in the batch script to parse the output and get the value from the `User profile` field which is set for the account in AD you run against that command.

### Script

```
@ECHO ON
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('net user <username> /domain ^| findstr /i "profile"') do set profilepath=%%a
echo %profilepath%
```

> **Script Notes**
>
> - This script assumes you will replace `<username>` below with the explicit value of the needed username when run to get the `Profile path` from the `net use xxx /domain` command.
> - The caret symbol in front of the pipe symbol ( i.e. `^|`)  within the brackets of the `for /f` loop pipes the output of the `net user`
>     command into the `findstr` command so it's there to escape the pipe
>     symbol so at command execution time within the loop it knows that's
>     redirecting one command's output as another commands input otherwise
>     it gets confused so simply escape it.
> - The percent sign has special meaning in batch scripts so when using a `for` loop within a batch script you need to double the percent sign
>     i.e. `%%a` of this placeholder to escape it ensuring it's interpreted
>     as a single `%` and can pass the variable accordingly within the loop.

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [FindStr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- `For /?`

  ```
  delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
                    default delimiter set of space and tab.
  tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
                    be passed to the for body for each iteration.
                    This will cause additional variable names to
                    be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
                    specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
                    the last character in the tokens= string is an
                    asterisk, then an additional variable is
                    allocated and receives the remaining text on
  ```
- [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)